# Locking buttons until next day

Tags: swift, uibutton

Is there anyway to lock buttons until the following day? For example, my app has coupons in the form of buttons and when you click the button "Coupon 1" it toggles to say "USED + the current date". I want the user to be able to only use 2 coupons per ViewController/page per dag, and am wondering if its possible to lock the other coupons once two are pressed by the user, and the coupons unlock the following day. I don't want the buttons to disappear, just want them to be locked. Below is the code for one of my buttons/coupons. It would be ideal if a lock actually appeared in the corner of the remaining buttons after 2 are pressed.

var didClick : Bool = false

```
@IBAction func special1BTNpressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !didClick {
        didClick = true
        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        let result = formatter.string(from: date)

        sender.setTitle("USED " + result, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Note:  Once you have a solution, you're going to have to use an external source for the date/time to prevent cheating by users who just set their clocks ahead a day.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the value of the date of which you did the action and then later compare it with today

```
func canPerformActionForSpecialBTN() -> Bool {

    let timeInterval = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "ActionDateForSpecialBTN")

    guard timeInterval.isNormal else { return true }

    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)

    guard Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date) else { return true }

    return false
}

func performSpecialBTNAction() {

    guard canPerformActionForSpecialBTN() else { return }

    defer { UserDefaults.standard.set(Date().timeIntervalSince1970, forKey: "ActionDateForSpecialBTN") }

    //implement action here

}
```

and maybe in the `viewDidAppear` you can enable or disable the button

button.isEnabled = !canPerformActionForSpecialBTN()

Comment: are you saying to write this code instead of the one that I included in my question @zombie

Comment: That was a example so maybe you can add it as it is or change the key for multiple actions